# Providing a formula for a function $f: \mathbb N\times\mathbb N \to\mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> (13) Consider $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ as a rectangular array: $$\begin{array}{cccc}(0,0)&(0,1)&(0,2)&(0,3)&\ldots\\(1,0)&(1,1)&(1,2)&(1,3)&\ldots\\(2,0)&(2,1)&(2,2)&(2,3)&\ldots\\(3,0)&(3,1)&(3,2)&(3,3)&\ldots\\\vdots\end{array}$$
>
> Count the elements of $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ using diagonals as follows: $$\begin{array}{cccccc}0&1&3&6&10&\ldots\\2&4&7&11&&\ldots\\5&8&12&&&\ldots\\9&13&&&&\ldots\\14&&&&&\ldots\\\vdots\end{array}$$
>
> This defines a function $$f:\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$$ where $f(m,n)$ is the number appearing in the $(m,n)$ place. (For example, $f(0,0)=0,f(3,1)=13,f(2,2)=12$.) Provide an explicit formula for $f$ (it is what one calls “a polynomial function in the variables $m,n''$. It may be a good idea to first find a formula for $f(0,n)$).

Trying to write a formula for $f(0,n)$, I can see that the value of $f(0,n)$ adds the $n$ value to the previous $f(0,n)$ element. But I don't know how to come up with a function for that.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? What's the "previous" element of a function?

Comment: Wikipedia: [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_pairing_function)

Answer (score 1):

The numbers $1,3,6,10,\cdots$ are the triangular numbers. Prove (using induction) that the $n$th triangular number $T_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: The key idea is that if $m+n=k$, then the $\langle m,n\rangle$ place is on the $(k+1)$-st diagonal, so there are $k$ whole diagonals of entries before it in the enumeration pictured. These diagonals use up the first

$$\sum_{i=1}^ki=\frac12k(k+1)=\frac12(m+n)(m+n+1)$$

values of $f$, i.e., the numbers $0$ through $\frac12k(k+1)-1$. Thus, entry at the top right of the $k$-th diagonal is $\frac12k(k+1)$, and as you go down the diagonal, the $f$ values increase in step with the row number $m$.

Answer (score 0):

For a function that fits for all nonegative integer pairs, take
$$f(m,n)=m+\dfrac{(n+m)(n+m+1)}{2}$$

Comment: is that proving by induction?

Comment: maybe, but this function is know since Cantor's time, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function for more